# What are the different values available for the Aptitude CLI “-q” option?

Tags: debian, aptitude

So I am creating some Vagrant provisioning scripts for some Ubuntu (14.04) boxes. I am using commands like this to install Ubuntu packages via Aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude install -y -q=2
```

Okay, I understand that `-q` and `-q=1` are functionally the same and that `-q=2` suppresses even more output.

But are there other values connected to `-q`? For example is there a `-q=3`, `-q=4` or even a `-q=5` value that can be set? And does it make any difference in the great scheme of things? Or does Aptitude only operate on a “greater than or equal to” basis and `-q=2` is the top limit?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this says it all `man aptitude`:

```
   -q[=<n>], --quiet[=<n>]
       Suppress all incremental progress indicators, thus making the
       output loggable. This may be supplied multiple times to make the
       program quieter, but unlike apt-get, aptitude does not enable -y
       when -q is supplied more than once.

       The optional =<n> may be used to directly set the amount of
       quietness (for instance, to override a setting in
       /etc/apt/apt.conf); it causes the program to behave as if -q had
       been passed exactly <n> times.
```

Here it says setting `-q` to the values indicated by you will be interpreted as **passing** `-q` that number of times.

So doing `-q=5` is equivalent to doing `-q -q -q -q -q`, but of course doing `-q=5` is much pleasing and readable. The operational difference is that it makes the program run far more quietly with respect to the number of `-q`s used.

Comment: „More quiet“ is quite unclear, don't you think? If I don't want any output, do I have to set `-q5` or `-q10000`, just to be sure? That's really bad documented there, and it's the same in **`info aptitude`** (where `man aptitude` may have stolen from, or the other way around). Btw `-qqq` doesn't work, I was mistaken there, it's `-q=3` or `-q3` or `-q -q -q`.